# php contact form not responding on clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in php with the below code:

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">

  <p><label> Your Name<br /> <span><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40"  required /></span> </label></p>
  <p><label> Your Email<br /> <span><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40"  required /></span> </label></p>
  <p><label> Your Message<br /> <span><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10"  required></textarea></span> </label></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>

</form>


<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $to = "contact@ghem.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['your_email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['your_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['your_message'];
    
    $subject = "Contact";
    $subject2 = "";
    $message = $first_name . " has sent you the following message.  Message:" . "\n\n" . $last_name. "\n\n" ."Email: ".$from. "\n\n" ;
    

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    // mail($last_name,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo '<div style="color:#5cad2f; "><b>Thank you ' . $first_name . ', we will contact you shortly.</b></div>';
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    
        }
?>
```

when I enter details and click submit button, nothing is happening, can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Is PHP installed and running?

Comment: @qirel, yes.. but this template is wordpress

Comment: @Qirel i mean same code i did with other websites in html template it was working, now this template is wordpress

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is happening"? Also, your HTML input name does not match with the names in your PHP script.

Comment: @ThumChoonTat i know the names are different, the problem is submit button is acting like static button, not redirecting or doing anything

Comment: Does it work if you replace the submit button with `button` element?

Comment: Form will be redirected to the same page because you haven't  give anything in action and have you used error_reporting in your code anywhere?

Comment: Why are you using wpcf7-form class on your form? This can lead the contact form plugin to interfere with your form.

Comment: have you check if any javascript on the page preventing submit button default action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to know your value is set or not like:

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
          echo "hello world";
     }
?>
```

when you click submit button if it display `hello world` that means `submit` work after that replace name as you show in your input field with `$_POST['your_name']`

Comment: thats not my problem. i know the names are different. the problem is submit button not responding, its static, not redirecting anywhere

Comment: comment whole code inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and just use `echo` with any message then it show you that your value is set or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should use same input name while getting POST values

```
$from = $_POST['your-email'];
 $first_name = $_POST['your-name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['your-message'];
```